# python3 upload files to ondrive or sharepoint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, upload, onedrive

Anyone know if this is possible?
I just want to automate dropping some documents into my onedrive for business account.

I tried

```
                import onedrivesdk
                from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
                from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

            redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
            client_id = 'appid'
            client_secret = 'mysecret'
            discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
            auth_server_url='https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?scope=wl.skydrive_update'
            #auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize',
            auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

            http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
            auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                            client_id,
                                            auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                            auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
            auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
            code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
            auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=resource)
            # If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
            # which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
            service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
            auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
            client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)
```

I registered an APP and got a secret and id. But when I ran this I got scope is invalid errors. Plus it tries to launch a webpage which isn't great for a command line kinda environment. I think this SDK might be outdated as well because originally this script had login.microsoftonline, but that wasn't reachable so I changed it to login.live.com.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this sample code you posted. You replaced the `auth_server_URL`with the authentication URL for Microsoft Account authentication, which can only be used to access OneDrive (the consumer product). You need to continue using the `login.microsoftonline.com` URL to log into your OneDrive for Business account.

You are correct that this pops up a dialog. However, you can write a little supporting code so that only happens the first time you log into a particular app. Follow these steps (assuming you are using the default implementation of `AuthProvider`:

1. Use the sample code above up through the line `auth.redeem_refresh_token()`
2. The `AuthProvider` will now have a `Session` object, which caches the credentials of the current user and session. Use `AuthProvider.save_session()` to save the credentials for later.
3. Next time you start your app, use `AuthProvider.load_session()` and `AuthProvider.refresh_token()` to retrieve the previous session and refresh the auth token. This will all be headless.

Take note that the default implementation of `SessionBase` ([found here](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/blob/master/src/onedrivesdk/session.py)) uses `Pickle` and is not safe for product use. Make sure to create a new implementation of `Session` if you intend to deploy this app to other users.

Comment: So it is supposed to work for corporate accounts as well? The code chokes on this line, and stays here forever :

`>>> auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)`

I'm using the original code, except for the secret and app id variables, on a Mac with python 2.7

Comment: My bad, I apologize for that, the code stalls on `code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)`, the next line

Answer (score 0):

Onerive's website shows "Not Yet" on "OneDrive SDK for Python" to "OneDrive for Business"
https://dev.onedrive.com/SDKs.htm

The github sample codes did not work for me either, it tried to popup a window of authentication, but IE can not find the address:

http://('https//login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize',)?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&client_id=034xxxx9-9xx8-4xxf-bexx-1bc5xxxxbd0c&response_type=code

or removed all the "-" in client id

http://('https//login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize',)?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&client_id=034xxxx99xx84xxfbexx1bc5xxxxbd0c&response_type=code

Either way, I got the same result, IE did not show the popup with a line "This page can’t be displayed"

Comment: After 2.5 years, it seems Graph API from Microsoft is working now, I successfully uploaded to OneDrive for Business with PHP SDK from their sample based on Lavarel framework.  [Microsoft Graph Starter project for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-rest-sample/tree/master/starter-project)